# How to print out Three numbers (inputs) in average and the largest number (input)

Tags: bash, shell, unix

By far, I can only get the numbers in average, but the largest number.

```
#! /bin/sh
# Get input numbers from user
 echo Please enter three numbers
 read a b c
# Calculate average of input numbers
avg=`expr \( $a + $b + $c \) / 3`
# Display the result
echo The average of the two input numbers is $avg
exit
```

Comment: @123: OP doesn't read the i/p's to an array, so might not apply for an exact duplicate, ain't it?

Comment: @Inian Same logic, and it is obviously better to use an array for this, so it may as well be a dup.

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
#! /bin/sh
# Get input numbers from user
 echo Please enter three numbers
 read a b c
# Calculate average of input numbers
avg=`expr \( $a + $b + $c \) / 3`


for i in $a $b $c ; do
    ((i > max)) && max=$i
done

echo The maximum number of the three input numbers is $max
# Display the result
echo The average of the three input numbers is $avg
exit
```

Comment: Did you just copy the answer from the duplicate...?

Comment: I only changed for loop to help;

Comment: Thanks for sharing